# How to verify with Boost Asio (C++) if the USB port is being used or not exist?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Is it possible to tell using Boost Asio whether a USB port is already in use, or it does not exist.

The function `Tools_Hardware_USB_Protocols_CDC_getDeviceNames` returns a vector of USB-port names.

The problem is that if the USB port is being used, an exception is thrown in the same way if the USB port does not exist.

How can I tell the difference?

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

void checkPort(std::vector<std::string>& deviceNames, char deviceName[]) {
    // Check if it already exist 
    if (CDCDeviceExist(deviceName)) {
        if (devices.at(deviceName)->is_open()) {
            deviceNames.push_back(deviceName);
        }
    }
    else {
        // Create temporary port
        boost::asio::serial_port device(io);
        device.open(deviceName);
        if (device.is_open()) {
            deviceNames.push_back(deviceName);
        }
        device.close();
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> Tools_Hardware_USB_Protocols_CDC_getDeviceNames() {
    // Get the names
    char deviceName[20];
    std::vector<std::string> deviceNames;
    for (int i = 0; i < 127; i++) {
        try {
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32) && !defined(__CYGWIN__)
            sprintf_s(deviceName, "COM%i", i);
            checkPort(deviceNames, deviceName);
#else
            sprintf_s(deviceName, "/dev/ttyAMC%i", i);
            checkPort(deviceNames, deviceName);
            sprintf_s(deviceName, "/dev/ttyUSB%i", i);
            checkPort(deviceNames, deviceName);
#endif

        }
        catch (...) {}
    }
    return deviceNames;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you catch the actual exception (instead of using `...`), you might be able to use the error code to distinguish. E.g.:

```
catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
     if (se.code() == /*error_code_or_condition*/) {
         // port doesn't exist
     } else {
         // some other failure
     }
}
```

Of course, the underlying API might not distinguish and then you have find a different API.

Comment: @euraad Did this actually work? If so, consider posting what error codes you receive on which platforms. I might check whether there's a portable error condition to check against as well. That way, we save others time in the future

Comment: Yes. It did work. The code was `boost::asio::error::no_permission`. If this is true, then the port is bussy and being used. Boost Asio is way much better than Libusb!